# The role of the Vandermonde determinant in representations of affine Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

I am reading a paper 'Yangians and R-matrices' by Chari & Pressley (1990) and to classify representations for particular quantum groups, they define a "quantum Vandermonde determinant". They also note that this plays the same role as the regular Vandermonde determinant plays in the classification of of integrable representations of affine Lie algebras. They reference a paper on representations of loop groups with that claim but I am yet to find where the Vandermonde determinant is used.

Is anyone able to shed any light on what role the Vandermonde determinant plays in the classification of integrable representations of affine Lie algebras?

Thanks

Comment: It's helpful here to add a link to the article you mention, which can be downloaded in PDF format: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1096420.  Here they refer you to their rather technical paper which can also be downloaded but uses Vandermonde determinants only indirectly: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002328356.   The subject is unfortunately rather notation-laden, so good luck.